# Is it possible to convert a pdf file to post script, then to text for see codes used in post script?

Tags: pdf, postscript, enscript

I have one pdf file where text have been formatted in tables, boxes, background colours. I tried to convert my text file to pdf with boxes, tables and background colours with enscript. I got success for foreground and background colours, but no tables and boxes. So I converted one pdf file to post-script to see what codes had been used for creating/inserting tables and boxes with text. I got success with PS codes but these are very difficult to understand. Then I converted .ps file to text, but now I can not see codes. I am hoping after understand post-script code I will use the same with `awk` as usual for pdf conversion. But no success. Is there any tool or command so I can see exact code used in post-script with text editor? I am using red hat linux 5.9.

Comment: I think postscript is just text: it is a stack based programming language. If you can't see it as text, then it may be compressed. Some GUI file-managers, will use the end of the file name (the bit after the last `.`) to determine how to open a file when you click on it.

Comment: There is always 2 option to open with document viewer and text editor. Document viewer is showing almost like pdf. Text editor shows post script codes for pdf. But those are difficult to understand.

Comment: What editor? Some have syntax highlighting, you may also need at tool to format it: put in non-functional spaces and newlines.

Comment: The program 'pstoedit' can produce the most readable postscript for editing. When using ghostscript pdf2ps be sure to avoid compressing the postscript with options: -dCompressPages=false -dCompressFonts=false -dCompressStreams=false for example.